# Serial Module Echoing a `0x00`

Tags: serial, rs485

I am having a problem with a MAXIM Serial module (Config A) with a simple repeating code from COM port. When sending a character (`k`:`0x6b`) I receive a (`0x00`) echo.

Without the module and just connecting the arduinos crossing the TX/RX cables, I do not have any echo.

The echo persists, disregarding of:

- The speed (from 38400 to 2000000 bps),
- Using or not the high speed options (2.3MOhm for 250000bps) of the MAXIM,
- Using or not 120 ohm terminal resistors,
- Both grounds are 0V, connecting them has no effect,
- Removing the `A` (red) `B` (green) Serial Bus Cables (???). Message not send in this case, as expected (!).

What could be the problem?

**Devices**:

- Two Arduino Mega 2560,
- Two [MAX3292](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3291-MAX3292.pdf), one for each arduino,
- AWG24 Cable, shorter than 7 in each.

**Config A**: With Module (`00` echo), Half Duplex (f.19 p.13).

[image: Config A]
[image: Config A Datasheet]

**Config B**: Without Module (No echo), only crossed cables

[image: Config B]

Code:

```
long rate=38400;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(rate); while (!Serial);
    Serial1.begin(rate); while (!Serial1);
    pinMode(22,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(23,OUTPUT);
}
char s;
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        digitalWrite(22,1);
        digitalWrite(23,1);
        s=Serial.read();
        Serial1.write(s);
        Serial1.flush();
        digitalWrite(23,0);
        digitalWrite(22,0);
    }
    if (Serial1.available()){
        s=Serial1.read();
        Serial.write(s);
    }
}
```

Execution: Four `k` sent, `0x00` echoes received. After this, four `k` send from other arduino, received successfully.

[image: Exec A]
[image]

**Epilogue.**

Actually, the problem was a resistor at the RO output, not shown in the diagram ("The problem is in the code you didn't post").

It was a voltage divider for a 5V3.3 conversion in the Arduino Due case, useless in the Arduino Mega, but still there.

Theorizing a reason, that resistor caused a spike at the output (?), thus forcing the module to interpret it as another byte, an empty one (?).

After removing the resistors, it worked perfectly. 
Now I migrated this back into Arduino Due, but with a diode plus a pull up resistor as a 5V3.3 converter.

Comment: You do have the grounds of the Arduinos connected together don't you?

Comment: All are plugged from a same USB splitter, but even connecting them in the breadboard, the effect persists.

Comment: Ok, looking in more detail - what code is at the other end? You have two megas, but only show one code.  Second - your terminal program is set to a different baud rate than your program.

Comment: Same code for both. The effect is the same for all speeds.

Comment: With that code for both, why do you expect anything to echo back? The 00 is the error, not the no response.

Comment: Yes, `the 0x00` is an error. No echo or response should be received. If I disconnect the AB bus, the echo is still there... If I remove the RE'DE signal, the echo dissapears (but no reception, since it is disabled).

Comment: Does your fritzing diagram precisely describe reality, or is your right-hand chip actually wired differently to how you are showing it?

Comment: It is almost exactly as the diagram. In a same breadboard, wiring the cables as named into the proper arduino. The named and the AB cables are about 7 in length.

Comment: So, you actually have your right-hand chip wired wrong? Inspect the wires going between the Arduino and the right hand chip...

Comment: Oh right, it is a drawing error (unfortunately?)... Already corrected.

Comment: Looks like you have wired it for the MAX3291 instead of the MAX3292.  Remove the PEE wire , since it's not PEE, it's PSET.  Connect a resistor and capacitor to VCC. Read page 11 of the datasheet.

Comment: I had them previously and i have just added them now, but unfortunately still the same echo, one per character in a string, after sending strings or sending individual characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your wiring! My guess is the twisted pair (A-B swap).

I've checked your code, it seems right. Please note that /RE and DE were designed that way so you can simply connect them and control with only one pin.

I don't have the exact same hardware, I had MAX485 and Arduino Nano at hand. Nano only has one hardware serial, so I've used the SoftwareSerial library instead.
I've connected them, adjusted your code to my setup, and it worked. Here it is in case it helps to troubleshoot your issue. I've also optimized your version a little bit (but it worked before so the bug is somewhere else).

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 4); // RX, TX

const int dir_pin=9;
const int dir_transmit=1;
const int dir_receive=0;
long rate=38400;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(rate); while (!Serial);
    mySerial.begin(rate); while (!mySerial);
    pinMode(dir_pin,OUTPUT);
}
char s;
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        digitalWrite(dir_pin,dir_transmit);
        while(Serial.available())
        {
          s=Serial.read();
          mySerial.write(s);
        }
        mySerial.flush();
        digitalWrite(dir_pin,dir_receive);
    }
    while (mySerial.available()){
        s=mySerial.read();
        Serial.write(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the code and the configuration was ok but... a resistor divider at the RO output not shown in the diagram was causing the problem. After removing it, everything worked fine. Thanks for the effort anycase...